# Spring JPA Many To One - One To Many Relationship with RestController

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve all Many To One relationship data from Postgresql database with Rest Controller with foreign key data. Like for Course and Instructor :

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "course_name": "IT 101",
        "instructor":{
            "instructor_name":"Jack King"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "course_name": "CS 101",
        "instructor":{
            "instructor_name":"Homer Love"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "course_name": "DB 101",
        "instructor":{
            "instructor_name":"Jack King"
        }
    }
}
```

My Code as follows:

### Database

```sql
create table instructor
(
    id          integer generated always as identity,
    instructor_name text,

    primary key (instructor_name),
    unique (id)
);

create table course
(
    id               integer generated always as identity,
    course_name text    not null,
    instructor_fk      integer references instructor (id),

    primary key (course_name, instructor_fk),
    unique (id)
);
insert into instructor (instructor_name) values ('Jack King');
insert into instructor (instructor_name) values ('Homer Love');

insert into author (course_name, instructor_fk) values ('IT 101', 1, 1);
insert into author (course_name, instructor_fk) values ('CS 101', 2, 2);
insert into author (course_name, instructor_fk) values ('DB 101', 3, 1);
```

### Entities

- I am using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations so instead of constractions, getters and setters for less boilerplate code.

#### Course

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String course_name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}  )
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_fk", nullable = false)
    private Instructor instructor;
}
```

#### Instructor

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String instructor_name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "instructor",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```

### Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {
}
```

### Service

```java
@Service
public class CourseService {
    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public List<Author> getAllCourses() {
        return (List<Author>) courseRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

### Controller

```java
@RestController
public class CourseController {
    @Autowired
    private CourseService courseService;

    @GetMapping("/courses")
    private List<Author> getAllCourses() {
        return courseService.getAllCourses();
    }
}
```

## What I get:

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "course_name": "IT 101"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "course_name": "CS 101"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "course_name": "DB 101"
    }
}
```

Comment: you add @JsonIgnore, the response will not have the `instructor`.

Comment: @PatrickChen I remove the JsonIgnore still the same.

Comment: Debug mode, try change your `cascade` to `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: I saw the problem JsonIgnore should be on OneToMany relation which means it should be on Instructor not on Course

Comment: I suspect json is valid or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JsonIgnore annotation should be on One To Many relation, which means it should be on Instructor entity not on Course entity:

#### Course

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String course_name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}  )
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_fk", nullable = false)
    private Instructor instructor;
}
```

#### Instructor

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String instructor_name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "instructor",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```